# How to update in PHP MYSql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update data. my table is.

```
ID Name Cat Points
1 John trainee 55
2 Ram manager 75
3 Shiva manager 80
4 Mark trainee 45
5 Mary intern 38
6 Tom trainee 60
```

from the above table i want to update only trainee in the cat field as 0. how to make it.

i know how to use all cat fields to zero.

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET `cat` = '0'";
```

the result should be like below.

```
ID Name Cat Points
1 John trainee 0
2 Ram manager 75
3 Shiva manager 80
4 Mark trainee 0
5 Mary intern 38
6 Tom trainee 0
```

Comment: all trainee 's Points must be 0 is that you ment?

Comment: Yeah @SajithaNilan : Example Also Given

Comment: I And Tim Already Wrote An Asnwer @SajithaNilan

Comment: but he need to do cat = 0 right? accordint to $sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET `cat` = '0'";

Comment: That must be the typo, i guess @SajithaNilan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE $tbl_name SET Points = 0 WHERE Cat = "trainee"';
```

Comment: i have tried, but i am getting this error  #1054 - Unknown column 'trainee' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET Points = 0 WHERE Cat = 'trainee'";
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'trainee' in 'where clause' i am getting this error

Comment: @only chande please mention your coloums clearly. so we can give you a better answer

Comment: $sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET `Points` = 0 WHERE `Cat` = 'trainee'"; try this @onlychande

Comment: Glad It Worked @onlychande